# Mostly static express app with one server side route

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs

I have an application that I'm developing using express that is almost a purely static site, with the exception of two forms that are posted to the server (a contact form and a request form). The site has roughly 10 static pages and two server side routes to accept the form submission.

I started developing the front end of the application with jade, stylus, and coffeescript, using grunt as both a development server and a build tool to output a production ready version (concat, min, etc..) of all these static assets.

Now onto the two server side routes. I'm curious what peoples thoughts are on this situation, where the app contains 90% static HTML, with only one or two server side routes.

So far I've considered three options:

**Option #1: Purely static HTML and "outsource" the two forms to someone like Wufoo**

This would eliminate the need for express altogether in production. I could continue to use grunt to build the application. However, I don't like this approach since I wouldn't have total control over the form submission. Not to mention, the number of form submissions with a free account is limited.

**Option #2: Purely server-side using express and Jade**

I don't like this approach either since I would define 10 or so server side routes, all of which simply render a jade template. Isn't that overkill? My routes would be littered with `app.get()` calls that contain a single `res.render()` in the callback. Also, even though we're probably talking milliseconds, why include middleware on pages that don't require it?

**Option #3: Mix of #1 and #2, using the express.static() middleware**

For this option, I would use something like [grunt-express](https://github.com/blai/grunt-express). This is my favorite option, however it seems a little "dirty" to mix client and server side jade templates. What I mean by this is that the express app would have (two) server side routes that are responsible for rendering a jade template. Mixing this with a call to `express.static()` that points to a directory that contains static HTML files that have been compiled from jade seems a little "dirty" to me. I'm not sure why.

If I choose option #3, how would my grunt build script work? Preferably, I would like the build to output a `dist/` folder which contained a production ready express app, including my tiny little `app.js` file.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: One options is to use another webserver (say Nginx) for static assets and keep Node.js only for dynamic content. I talk a little bit about this approach here: http://hectorcorrea.com/#/blog/running-a-node-js-web-site-in-production-part-2/53

Comment: I actually really like this idea, but wasn't sure how the two (front end and back end) would co-exist since I have multiple express apps running on the server. I'll read the linked blog. Can you provide a detailed answer? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option #2**

res.render(...) is very smart

- It will not generate HTML again (if you do not change res.locals)
- Beside that render has smart cache control, it will send "304 Not Modified" to browsers, instead of whole body.

Just use Option #2, and make sure browsers get 304 for static content. If you just a newbie to nodejs, make sure you start your node in 'production' mode, because jade is slow in 'development'.

Answer (score 0):

You can render all the server side templates with something like

```
app.get('/:template', function (req, res) {
    res.render(req.params.template);
});
```

Comment: How would this work with a 404? One of the reasons I don't like this is because the request has to run through any unnecessary middleware. I would also like to minify the HTML to improve performance.

Comment: You'd want to flesh this out with some existence checking or use a regex like `/:template(page1|page2|page3)` or whatever. But I think you should pick one, live with it for a while, and switch to something else when you understand the pain points. For a small site, it's a good habit to just try for yourself without needing to survey and debate on stackoverflow.

Comment: The only reason I outlined three potential options is because I already put some thought into it. I could have proposed the question as "how should I handle serving mostly static HTML (jade) templates with an express app?"